# How to link a slider and checkbox to a counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, slider

I am new in JavaScript. I am trying to link a slider and checkbox to a counter. The slider should increase the counter's value depending on the range. And then the checkboxes have fixes values depending on the users(the slider's value are users, I will explain later) that they should add to the counter if it is checked or not.

```
var slider = document.querySelector('#myRange');                               //Input
var output = document.querySelector("#value-range");                           //Output
let rangeValue = document.querySelector('#final-price');                       //Counter
const boxesContainer = document.querySelector('.price-boxes__container');      //Checkboxes
```

I created an event for the checkboxes, so when you click on it, adds the value.

```
boxesContainer.onchange = function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('checkbox')){
        const price = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('value'))
        if (e.target.checked === true) {
            total += price;
        } else {
            total -= price;
        }
        rangeValue.innerHTML = total
    }
}
```

And I created another event for the slider as well.

```
slider.oninput = function () {
    let value = slider.value;
    userPrice(value)    
    output.style.left = (value/2.88);
    output.classList.add("show");
    rangeValue.innerHTML = prices[value-25];
       
    function userPrice (value) {
        if (value == 25) {
            output.innerHTML = '6 €p'
        } else {
            output.textContent = `${prices[value-25] - prices[value-26]} €p`;
        }
    }
}
```

The slider has min 25, max 1000, step = 1, value = 25. Each step is one user. I created an array that has the price depending on the slider's value. Between 26-50 users 6€ per user, 51-250 4€/p, 251-500 3€/p and 501-1000 2€/p. Therefore, I thought the easy way was to create an array and use the slider's value to sent the price to the counter.

```
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
let rangePrices = range(25, 1000, 1);

const prices = [];

rangePrices.forEach((rangeValue, i)=> {
    if(rangeValue === 25) {
        prices.push(299)
    } else if (rangeValue < 51) {
         prices.push(prices[i-1] + 6)
    } else if (rangeValue < 251){
        prices.push(prices[i-1] + 4)
    } else if (rangeValue < 501) {
        prices.push(prices[i-1] + 3)
    } else {
        prices.push(prices[i-1] + 2)
    }
});
```

But at the end, when I click on the checkboxes the counter adds the checkboxes' values, but it resets. I know that I have two rangeValue.innerHTML and is due to this that it does not work, but I do not know how to fix it...

As I said at the beginning the checkbox depends on the slider value. Between 26-50 0.7€/p.u., 51-250 0.5€/p.u., 251-500 0.4€/p.u. and 501-1000 0.3€/p.u.. Therefore, so the checkboxes are related to the slider. I do not know how to link both functions either. Finally say that there are 2 more checkboxes.

It would be great if someone could help me!

https://jsfiddle.net/NilAngelats/wq7tjh8c/

Comment: When are you firing `rangePrices.forEach`? Is it inside a function or on page load?

Comment: It is above the const prices

Comment: Yes that code is executed when? I would say you have a problem with scope.

Comment: Oh, is on a page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
let total = 0;

boxesContainer.onchange = function(e) {
    ...
    rangeValue.innerHTML = prices[slider.value - 25] + total
}

slider.oninput = function() {
    ...
    rangeValue.innerHTML = prices[value - 25] + total;
}
```

And move `userPrice` function out of the `slider.oninput` function so it's only declared once and not every time you move the slider.